# How can I transfer data from my iPhone 11 Pro to my new iPhone 14 Pro? Why is my backup so large?

Tags: iphone, itunes, icloud, backup

Like the title says, I've got a new iPhone 14 Pro and I'm trying to transfer data from my old phone to my new one, but I run into a lot of errors. As far as I know, there's three official ways for me to transfer data: quick start, iCloud restore, and PC restore. I've tried all of them and they haven't worked so far.

Quick Start works until the old phone says, "Finish on New iPhone" and the new phone says "Preparing to transfer..." It will be stuck like that for 40-60 minutes when the process stops on its own with no warning and the new phone says, "Data Transfer Canceled Reset iPhone to start setting up again."

iCloud backup has not been working for my old phone. I'm using the complimentary iCloud storage used to restore data onto my new phone. Usually, it gets to 5% "Estimating time remaining..." and then fails after an hour or two with "The last backup could not be completed." It has worked once, with estimated time remaining of 10+ hours so I left it to run overnight. When I awoke, it said the backup failed. I checked the backups and there was a backup of ~700 GB (Yes, seven hundred). In the details with the app listings, it says there was no data, so I could not identify what that ~700 GB was.

Finally, with a PC local iTunes backup (Windows 10), the Sync step 2 takes 1-2 hours to prepare and then the progress bar begins to move very slowly. I've done it once and it filled my C drive so I stopped it. Further attempts said a "session could not be created with the device." I currently have the phone backing up to an external SSD and tricked iTunes to relocate the local backup data with directory linking with the command prompt. I am closely monitoring the process and currently the backup size is 275 GB. It's been about 6 hours. For reference, my iPhone 11 Pro reports that I have used 46.5 GB of 64 GB available. The progress bar is over a third full so I fear that the backup will attempt to become ~700 GB again.
[image: window of folder properties displaying backup folder as 275 GB]

I've spoken to Apple support with no success so far. I will continue to troubleshoot with them, but for now I am making this post to see if others have run into a similar issue and if I can get any help or advice. I've found one case of a similar issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253702231

Below is my iTunes window.

[image: itunes window showing phone model and size as well as backup progress and information]

Comment: Question... what is the phone authoritative for that it actually matters whether or not you migrate it?

Comment: @MarcWilson I'm not sure I understand your question. If you're asking why I want to migrate my data to my new phone instead of manually setting it up, it's just that I would rather have it be a seamless transition between my old phone and my new phone. There's a lot of settings and preferences and data I won't have set up exactly as my old phone which would bother me a lot.